# Changing the title plugin page in admin panel

Tags: wordpress

I use `admin_title`.

```js
function filter_admin_title($admin_title, $title) {
  return "test";
}

// add the filter
add_filter("admin_title", "filter_admin_title", 10, 2);
```

[image]

Why the following error happens?

Comment: I think you forgot to write the error. The function is right, which error do you receive?

Comment: the function didn't work, it didn't give any error either

Comment: Where did you put the code?

Comment: function.php in theme child

Comment: This is very weird because the function is correct (I even tested on my server), put `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 1);` before and inside the function to see if there's any error happening.

Comment: @Lucius it worked when i set priority to 999

Comment: Greeat! nice :)